# Is there any alternative to circumvent 500MB Template restore limit?

Tags: 2010, list, restore, template

I need to restore a template with size greater than 500MB. Is it possible to circumvent the limit?

Comment: that was for WSS 3.0... this is for SP2010

Comment: I agree it was for WSS 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open SharePoint 2010 Management Shell and run the following PowerShell:

```
$docSize = 50000000
$webservice = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$webservice.MaxTemplateDocumentSize = $docSize
$webservice.Update()
```

Accroding to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebservice.maxtemplatedocumentsize%28v=office.14%29.aspx), it should be between 0-500MB, but you can go beyond 500MB AFAIK.

Comment: How to go beyond 500MB?

Comment: Erm - set $docSize greater than 500MB at a rough guess.